# If f is a continuous map from X to Y with X limit point compact, does it follow that f(X) is limit point compact?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

I'm looking for proof verification/help for the title question. Here is what I have now:

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous with $X$ limit point compact. Let $V$ be an infinite subset of $f(X)$. Then we also have that $f^{-1}(V)$ is also an infinite subset of $X$. Since $X$ is limit point compact there is $x \in X$ such that $x$ is a limit point of $f^{-1}(V)$. Then $x \in \overline{f^{-1}(V)}$ by definition of the closure. Hence since $f$ is continuous,
$$
f(x) \in f(\overline{f^{-1}(V)}) \subseteq \overline{f(f^{-1}(V))} \subseteq \overline{V}
$$
Then since $f(x) \in \overline{V}$, it is either a limit point of $V$ or an element of $V$. However since is infinite, any neighborhood of $f(x)$ will contain infinitely many points of $V$ in either case. Thus $V$ has a limit point and $f(X)$ is limit point compact.

Comment: Also if this is wrong, please don't just post the answer. Give me hints/tips on where I went wrong so that I can fix it myself.

Comment: You can assume WLOG that $x \notin f^{-1}(V)$, so that $f(x) \notin V$. And then you are done.

Comment: I don't believe that assuming $x\notin f^{-1}(V)$ is in fact without loss of generality. And if $f(x)\in V$, then I don't see why any neighborhood of $f(x)$ must contain infinitely many points of $V$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your statement does not hold in general.

Here is a counterexample: Take $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology and $\{0,1\}$ with the indiscrete topology.
Then $X = \mathbb{R} \times \{0,1\}$ with product topology.

$X$ is limit point compact. Take any subset $A\subset X$, then
if $(a,0) \in A$, $(a,1)$ is a limit point of $A$  because
all neighborhoods of $(a,1)$ also contain $(a,0)$ (by definition of topology of $\{0,1\}$ and product topology). Similarly if $(a,1) \in A$, $(a,0)$ is a limit point of $A$

But the projection map onto $\mathbb{R}$ (just the real line..) is continuous, while the real line is not limit point compact (say $\mathbb{N}$ has no limit point).

For your proof , I don't quite understand "However since is infinite, any neighborhood of $f(x)$ will contain infinitely many points of $V$ in either case". In particular, what if $f(x)$ is an element of $V$?

Comment: Yeah that's true, I guess I let myself think only about $\mathbb{R}$ instead of a general space. Thank you.

Comment: @Kersen I am glad it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Let A be an infinite subset of$ f(X)$. Then $A$ = {${f(x)|x ∈
B}$} where B ⊆ X is infinite. Since $X$ is limit point compact, B has a limit
point $b$. Let $V_b$ be a neighborhood of $f(b)$. Then, since $f$ is continuous,
there exists some neighborhood $U_b$ of  $ b$ such that $f(U_b) ⊆ Vb$. Since $b$ is a limit point of $B$, there exists some $y ∈ B$ such that $y \neq  b$$,  y ∈ U_b.$ Thus,
$f(y) ∈ f(Ub) ⊆ Vb,$
so, since $f(y) ∈ A$, $V_b$ intersects $A$ at some point other than $f(b)$. Since
our choice of neighborhood for $f(b)$ was arbitrary, we conclude that every
neighborhood of $f(b)$ intersects $A$ somewhere other than$ f(b)$, meaning $f(b)$is a limit point of $A$. Since our choice of infinite subset$ A $was arbitrary,
we conclude that every infinite subset of $f(X)$ has a limit point, so $f(X)$ is
limit point compact.

Comment: How do you know $f(b)\neq f(y)$?

Comment: John's answer is a counter example. As Not Euler points out you haven't actually proven that $V_b$ intersects $f(X)$ at a point other than $f(b)$.